# why am I getting multiple firebase uid for same email id even after selecting option of "prevent users from creating multiple accounts"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have selected the option of "Prevent users from creating multiple accounts". (screen shot attached).

[image: screenshot1]

Even then for one of the accounts, I get the following details(screenshot). The email is same but there are 3 different Uid. On top of that 2 uids have the same provider(google).

[image: screenshot2]

I visited this link, but I never opted multiple accounts for one email id.

[Firebase: One account per email is enabled still, firebase creating multiple accounts with same email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914494/firebase-one-account-per-email-is-enabled-still-firebase-creating-multiple-acc)

What steps should I take so that there is always only one uid per email.

Comment: More information is needed to help determine the cause. There may be a race condition in your app (sign in for the same email is called multiple times simultaneous). Or the account could have been created before you enabled this setting, or you uploaded multiple accounts with the same email via the Admin SDK `importUsers` API.

Comment: Account was created after the settings was enabled. Admin SDK was not used. Only thing could be the race condition which is driving me nuts because I am not able to reproduce it. Is there any way to simulate condition that mimic the race conditions? I am writing simple synchronous code.